# The point $(0,1)$ on coordinate axis, and any point on a single line look the same. [whereas $(0,0)$ is not]

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I am trying to show that 
$S_{1}^{-1}[K[X,Y]/(XY)]$ is isomorphic as rings to $S_{2}^{-1}K[X]$, where $K$ is a field, $S_{1}=(k[X,Y]/(XY))\setminus(\bar{X},\bar{Y}-1)$, and $S_{2}={\{1,X,X^2,\dots}\}$. Is the question true? If true, what is the isomorphism map? If not, then why?

Answer (score 1):

The first ring is isomorphic to $K[Y]_{(Y-1)}$, while the second is isomorphic to $K[X,X^{-1}]$. It seems that the first is local and the second is not.

**Edit.** It is well known and not difficult to prove that $(R/I)_{\mathfrak m/I}\simeq R_{\mathfrak m}/I_{\mathfrak m}$. In our case we take $R=K[X,Y],$ $I=(XY)$ and $\mathfrak m=(X,Y-1)$. Notice that $(XY)_{(X,Y-1)}=(X)_{(X,Y-1)}$ (since $Y\notin (X,Y-1)$), use the above isomorphism again (where this time $I=(X)$) together with $K[X,Y]/(X)\simeq K[Y]$.

Comment: How to show that the first ring is isomorphic to $K[Y]_{(Y-1)}$? What is the map?

Comment: @YACP, Could you explain how you get that $k[x,y]/(xy)$ localized at the maximal ideal $(x, y-1)$ is $k[y]$ localized at the prime ideal $(y-1)$?

Comment: @tzuchoco The answer is edited now. Hope it is clear. If you find my answer useful, then accept it, Otherwise feel free to ask and comment.